# laspy ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size

Tags: python-2.7, lidar, las, fusion, laspy

I am trying to learn LASPY and am running into road blocks off the bat. I first ran into and Error 8 (Not enough storage is available to process this command) using my full sized LAS file (1.7GB). I was able to get around it by using FUSION's polyclipdata to create multiple smaller sized LAS files; just frustrating. The second road block I have run into, and I can't find out much about it, is:

```
ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
```

when I try:

```
import laspy
import numpy as np
from laspy import file
infile = file.File("F:/P834/temp/pointfile3_2.las", mode="r")
```

Error occurs on line 4.

I am trying to work through the tutorial http://laspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tut_part_1.html

What am I missing in my early start?

Full error printout:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/P834/laspy/laspy_tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    infile = laspy.file.File('F:/P834/temp/pointfile3_2.las', mode='r')
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\laspy\file.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\laspy\file.py", line 75, in open
    self._reader = base.Reader(self.filename, mode=self._mode)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\laspy\base.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.setup_read_write(vlrs,evlrs, read_only=True)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\laspy\base.py", line 321, in setup_read_write
    self.data_provider.point_map()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\laspy\base.py", line 163, in point_map
    offset=self.manager.header.data_offset)
ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
```

Comment: Are you importing the tiled las data from FUSION?

Comment: I tiled the data using fusion in the command prompt. The only code in my python window currently is what is displayed above.

Comment: In other words, using `laspy`, are you trying to import a tiled las file that was created using FUSION?

Comment: Yes. This is the first part of the tutorial and I couldn't get past the memory error without tiling.

Comment: You may be trying to import a corrupted file. Try importing another las file using `laspy` to see if your tiled las data is in fact corrupted: http://matsu.gina.alaska.edu/LiDAR/Caswell_Lakes/Point_Cloud/Classified/CL_001_NE_PtCl.las

Comment: That file worked, i can see the results.... how do I do this for my larger dataset?

Comment: Now, we have to figure out why FUSION corrupted your file during the tiling process. That may be a question in and of itself...

Comment: As a side note, I have been enjoying working with the R `lidR` package recently and would recommend it over laspy. It is highly optimized for working with point cloud data with an emphasis on forestry applications.

Comment: I will look into R, I have no experience with it currently. I am looking for the best (and easiest) method to learn to get at the data in LAS files for exactly that: forestry applications. I have placed the FUSION question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273053/fusion-polyclipdata-creates-corrupt-las-file

Comment: Great, thanks for opening a new question. I would recommend either adding your own answer to this question (e.g. I was working with corrupt data) or closing this question so that we can consider this question resolved. Also, if you are interested in the `lidR` package, check out @JRR's github page which has many tutorials: https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR

Answer (score 2):

As determined while working through the problem with Aaron, I figured out I was working with corrupt data, because applying the same code to other .las file worked ([here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/8104/aaron) is the alternative file used).

I have opened another question related to why FUSION is creating corrupt data when using the polyclipdata module here: [FUSION polyclipdata creates corrupt LAS file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273053/fusion-polyclipdata-creates-corrupt-las-file)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error with las files containing EXTRA_BYTE information generated with lasheight from LAStools. After removing the EXTRA_BYTE information laspy had no issue to open the files.