# FUSION's PolyClipData creates corrupt LAS file?

Tags: python, clip, lidar, fusion, laspy

I am trying to learn LASPY and am following a [tutorial](http://laspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tut_part_1.html). I got an error when starting up using:

```
import laspy
infile = laspy.file.File("./laspytest/data/simple.las", mode="r")
```

where I got a storage error:

```
LaspyException: Error mapping file: [Error 8] Not enough storage is available to process this command
```

To try and get around this I tried FUSION's polyclipdata routine to parse the LAS file into 4 parcels:

```
command = 'polyclipdata /multifile ' + temp + '\\pointfile2.shp ' + temp + '\\pointfile3.shp {}'.format(in_las_file)
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 
(stdoutdata, stderrdata) = process.communicate()
if stderrdata:
   print stderrdata
```

When I try and work with LASPY again, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
```

I thought that this was a LASPY error and created a question to resolve it, however, after testing "clean" data, LASPY was determined to not be the problem ([laspy ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273045/laspy-valueerror-buffer-size-must-be-a-multiple-of-element-size?noredirect=1#comment435147_273045)). I am using Python 2.7.

Why is FUSION's `polyclipdata` not producing a usable product?

I started looking into R's lidr package and ran the `readLAS` command. I got the following messages:

```
ERROR: 'end-of-file' after 8196120 of 8196121 points
Warning messages:
1: Invalid file: header states the file contains 8196121 points but 8196120 were found. Header has been updated. 
2: Invalid file: header states the file contains 7570432 1st returns but 1028359 were found. Header has been updated. 
3: Invalid file: header states the file contains 482368 2nd returns but 979894 were found. Header has been updated. 
4: Invalid file: header states the file contains 114533 3rd returns but 936803 were found. Header has been updated. 
5: Invalid file: header states the file contains 25014 4th returns but 997835 were found. Header has been updated. 
6: Invalid file: header states the file contains 3477 5th returns but 1053020 were found. Header has been updated. 
7: 7369979 points below 0 found. 
8: Dataset is invalid: 1049976 points with a return number of 0 found.
```

It looks as though the datasets created by FUSION messed up the header?